# SPDT Relay XOR Gate

Tags: logic-gates

I've been trying to build some logic circuits with some SPDT relays I got for quite a while now and am quite confused. I've been able to make all of the basic logic circuits out of them except for the XOR gate.

This is probably a beginner question, but I *am* a beginner and can't find information on this anywhere. A diagram or explanation of a possible circuit would be made; preferably with only two relays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine the two way switch set up that can switch on and off a lamp in your hall from two different positions. That is the EXOR function - two mutually exclusive switches wired up so that either switch can invert the state of the lamp. How do they do that? Do you know? Can you figure that out? I'm not going to help further because you should do some research on this.